# Is it possible to load a dumped process?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, assembly, process

I was wondering if it's possible to dump a process and then load it into memory, so it will be in the same state as when it was dumped.
For example, I open notepad.exe and type something into it. I save its memory into a file and then I can load it whenever I want and it has the text I typed before.
How can it be done?

Comment: Isn't that what Perl used to do?

Comment: You want to do this with an arbitrary external process that is unaware of what you are about to do?

Comment: This is not trivial and would need to be done at the kernel level. It would need to be loaded back in at the same address space with the same memory layout. You'll also have to manage opened file handles, not all of which can be restored when you load the application. You'll also have to prevent other process from modifying files the app had opened otherwise the app may not like it very much. If that's not what you mean your question is unclear, otherwise it's too broad.

Comment: The answer to your question: Yes, this is possible. The system does exactly that to implement the [S4 Sleeping State](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff564575.aspx). If you want to do this yourself, be prepared for a **steep** learning curve. If you have to ask, you are years away from a working implementation.

Comment: Well, if you cause a coredump, this is precisely what a debugger does with the coredump file.

Comment: @DaviHoelzer: This is not the case with Minidump files generated on Windows. Even a full memory dump is not something you can load into a debugger and hit `g`.

Answer (score 0):

No, in general it's not practical to do this without rewriting the operating system to support it. While you could in theory save a process's memory and register state to a file and restore exactly the same in a new process, you'd still be missing things. None of the old process's handles would still be valid. It's not just file handles, but things like window handles as well. None of the old process's windows would exist in the new process. You could recreate them, but without cooperation from the operating system there's no way to ensure the that window handles for the newly created windows would have the value as the handles for the old windows.

Note that for certain types of handles Windows actually randomizes part of handle, meaning even if you knew what order they were allocated in, you still couldn't get the old handle values.